# Pass data between more than two view controllers using delegation

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, delegation

First of all, let me say that I have been using the delegation pattern to pass data back and forward between view controllers for quite some time without any issues but now I have a need to pass data between four (4) view controllers, `ViewController1`, `ViewController2`, `ViewController3` and `CategoriesViewController`.

In the code below I'm showing the communication between `ViewController1` and the `CategoriesViewController`, the communication between `ViewController2` and `CategoriesViewController` will be identical as well.

My issue or what I don't quite like is the fact that I don't need to pass any data between `ViewController3` and the `CategoriesViewController` so, my debate is how can I handle the fact that `CategoriesViewController` is expecting variable `categoryTracker` which I will not be passing when connecting `ViewController3` with the `CategoriesViewController`.

Is there a way to make the variable `categoryTracker` in `CategoriesViewController` optional, here I'm talking in a sense that I wouldn't have to pass it when connecting from `ViewController3` and NOT a `Swift` optional?

How would you guys do such communication in a way that `CategoriesViewController` becomes more modular/reusable?

### ViewController1 and ViewController2

```
class ViewController1: UIViewController, CategoryDelegate{

    @IBAction func showCategories(_ sender: Any) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "categoriesViewControllerID") as? CategoriesViewController
        
        vc?.delegate = self
        vc?.categoryTracker = self.categorySelection
        
        self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

### CategoriesViewController

```
protocol CategoryDelegate {
    func selectedCategory(category: Category)
}

class CategoriesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var delegate: CategoryDelegate?
    var categoryTracker:Category?

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        delegate?.selectedCategory(category: categoryTracker!)
    }
}
```

#### Just for reference, here is how ViewController3 would look like.

```
class ViewController3: UIViewController{

    @IBAction func showCategories(_ sender: Any) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "categoriesViewControllerID") as? CategoriesViewController            
        self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Basically this inchworm forward and back shuttling of data is just wrong. A view controller arguably has no business even knowing that other view controllers exist. Consider a centralized data model that all VCs can subscribe to. I call this approach DataLand. This is now easy to implement safely and automatically thanks to the Combine framework.

Comment: Hmm, I thought the `Combine framework` was specifically for `SwiftUI`. Either way that sounds a little too complex and above my knowledge. Do you have a tutorial on `DataLand` in any of your books?

Comment: No but I have a free book about Combine! And it is most certainly not for just SwiftUI. https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/

Comment: Also look at the 2019 videos about multiple windows. What if you have two windows open simultaneously? Those view controllers can’t even see each other, yet what happens in one must be instantly reflected in the other. That can only happen if everything reflects up into DataLand and back down.

Comment: Oh, great, I will take a look at your free book. Hmm, interesting point, I never thought about, I thought delegation was what Apple recommends. In short, how would describe `DataLand`? Is it like a class with a bunch of variables that can be updated from other classes (view controllers) that are subscribed to it?

Comment: Yes, exactly, although I don't think you want other classes to have the ability to set its properties _directly_. It needs to be a class because we want reference semantics; it might be a singleton. It might define a protocol of things other classes can say to it. It might have instance properties that publish themselves whenever they change; Combine really helps here with `@Published` — otherwise you would probably have to use KVO or a setter observer that emits a notification (or some other reactive framework like RxSwift).

Comment: I enjoyed discussing it with you.